# PostgreSQL: Select several queries into same table

Tags: postgresql, select, select-into

Good day,

I have a table with some records that should be deleted.  I would like to keep track of the deleted records and place such records in a new table.  I would like to do the following:

```
SELECT * INTO TEMP FROM TABLE WHERE criteria < 1;
```

And then delete these records with DELETE query.  Later on I would like to do a new SELECT query:

```
SELECT * INTO TEMP FROM TABLE WHERE new_criteria > 2;
```

And then delete those records as well.  I will be working from only one table and just place the selected records into the same, new table (just for reference).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO temp (SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE criteria < 1);
```

Comment: Parenthesis are just noise here, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Does you temp table have the same structure as the original. if the temp does not exist you might want to do this.

```
create table temp as select * from TABLE where criteria <1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postgresql 9.3 You could also do everything in one command:

```
WITH deleted_rows AS (
    DELETE FROM tbl
    WHERE criteria<1
    RETURNING *
)
INSERT INTO temp
SELECT * FROM deleted_rows;
```

(see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING )